QGIS style with Transparent Gradient Fill with a Non-Transparent Outline
I’m trying to create a style in QGIS that combines:

A transparent gradient fill for polygons.

A fully opaque outline (stroke).


However, I’ve noticed that when I adjust the opacity of the symbol, it seems to apply to both the fill and the outline.
Ideally, I want the fill to be semi-transparent (e.g., 50%) while keeping the outline completely opaque (100%).
Thank you
